# On iOS devices, how to check date time settings

Tags: ios, objective-c

In iOS, is there a way in the SDK to query the device settings to determine if date/time is being set manually or automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can only check it on a jailbroken device which is not sandboxed (i.e. needs to be root). Which kind of makes sense.

Otherwise, you should be able to do it by:

```
BOOL TMIsAutomaticTimeEnabled();
BOOL TMIsAutomaticTimeZoneEnabled();
```

after adding com.apple.timed to your app entitlements.